# Creating a custom URL to redirect to on Win 2003 Server

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, domain

How can I setup a domain so that it redirects to another address for example;

http://itsupport.home

redirects to:
http://www.longdifficult.com/to-remeber/address/1865622

It only needs to be within our network, but the site it redirects to is on the internet. The DNS server is on a Win 2003 Sp2 Maachine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look at your DNS server, and create a CNAME. The following URL should give you some more information on what is required and the purpose of a CNAME.

[MICROSOFT KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324260)

I can provide more indept instructions if required.

Comment: Sorry did you say you had a URL? I am aware of the basics of a CNAME I'm just not sure how to create in Server 2003. I tried to create a new CNAME record in the DNS zone but it didn't work

Comment: hi sorry i thought I had linked it in!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do http redirection, one of the easiest is to set up a web site whose sole purpose is to redirect to another URL. DNS doesn't do URL redirection - you can create a CNAME for itsupport.com to point to www.longdifficult.com - but it won't care about handling the rest of the difficult URL for you.

Simply set up a web site in IIS that responds to the itsupport.home host header (binding) and have that web site action be to redirect to another URL; the long and difficult one. Then if not already done, add the itsupport.home A Record to point to this IIS server's IP (or a CNAME to its host name) in your DNS system.

[image: IIS redirect to URL dialog]