# Regarding Cnames, A Records (Internal Network Forwarding to External Domain)

Tags: domain-name-system, iis, cname-record

It is not possible to do a redirect from internal DNS to external domain correct?

We have a subdomain test.internaldomain.com and internally we want it to point to external url, including full path: http://externaldomain.com/pages/longpath

Obviously I can make an A record for the subdomain and point it to the IP of the external domain, but that only resolves to their root domain (or whatever they have their IP resolving to).

I haven't done this for a while. There isn't a way to do this correct?

Is this option below the best option? Creating additional IIS site simply used for redirect?
[Creating a custom URL to redirect to on Win 2003 Server](https://serverfault.com/questions/219410/creating-a-custom-url-to-redirect-to-on-win-2003-server)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Typically people do a redirect from `internaldomain.com` or if they want to hide the external domain they do a reverse proxy.  Both of these are handled by the webserver and not by DNS.